# Calculating CSS font-size for mobile

Tags: css, font-size, retina

I have to calculate correct font-size for mobile. The mock-up guide I'm getting is the size of the real resolution of an iPhone 5 (640x1136). Tinkering with it, I soon realized I have to divide any value in the guide by 2, to get the correct logical font-size. Consider meta tag `viewport` present in HTML.

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: The minimum font size for phone should be at least 16px , you can go through with the blog here for the correct approach http://typecast.com/blog/a-more-modern-scale-for-web-typography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a good approach because the it is the retina screen which is actually the double of the normal resolution. like for Iphone6 we have the retina screen of `750 * 1334`. But when we inspect it shows `375 * 667` so therefor it is a good approach to divide by two if mockups are provided according to retina screen.